# Dynamics CRM, Skype for Business integration

Tags: sdk, crm, microsoft-dynamics, skype-for-business

We have a client running Dynamics CRM Online, and they're moving over to Skype for Business (S4B) as their "PBX". I see you can use the Lync 2013 SDK to listen for call answering and dialing etc. from S4B, but I would like to be able to get the Contact ID on the Contact record when a user clicks to dial from in CRM and run some code against it. Are there options to have CRM run code when the dial button is pushed, or should I use S4B Lync SDK to wait for the event (if I do it this way, does CRM pass the Contact ID or similar to S4B for me to use)?

I hope this makes sense - I'm still getting my head around this...

Thanks
James

Comment: If click to dial is linked to a a pipeline event you could register a plugin on it,

Comment: Thanks James - I thought of that, but I don't know where to find out if this is the case? As far as I understand it's a client event, and I can't see any CRM support for catching it using JavaScript either?

Comment: Could you remove the standard CRM button and add your own?